# percentage difference with month and year and count in table using DAX

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax

I am trying to get percentage difference with month and year using DAX function

```
Month   Year          records
Jan      2015          100
Feb      2015          120
Mar      2015          140
Apr      2015          160
```

and I am trying to  calculate percentage diff in a new column

```
Month    Year          records   %change
Jan      2015          100        0%
Feb      2015          120        20%
Mar      2015          140        17.02%
Apr      2015          180        22%.03
```

Comment: You want the percentage difference from Jan to end of Year or since first record?

Comment: Yes ,But i have issue here, I have Months in 2016 and 2017 also how i can % of rise and fall of records with month and year

Comment: Use some date tables and this would be no sweat.

Comment: What change are you trying to calculate?  Are you sure your values in the %change column are correct? The values in my answer are different.

Comment: Value that i mentioned are incorrect

Answer (score 2):

In your current setup, something like this could work. Using a datetable would be better and easier though.

```
%change = 
VAR StartLastMonth =
    ( DATE ( 'table'[Year], 'table'[Month] - 1, 1 ) )
VAR RecordsLastMonth =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'table'[Records] ),
        FILTER (
            'table',
            'table'[Year] = YEAR ( StartLastMonth )
                && 'table'[Month] = MONTH ( StartLastMonth )
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( RecordsLastMonth ),
        BLANK (),
        'table'[Records] - RecordsLastMonth
    )
        / RecordsLastMonth
```

[image]

Comment: I am using this calculation  and i got the below error .

Comment: =VAR StartLastMonth =
    ( DATE ( 'CalculatedTable 2'[Year], 'CalculatedTable 2'[monthname] - 1, 1 ) )
VAR CountsLastMonth =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'CalculatedTable 2'[Counts] ),
        FILTER (
            'CalculatedTable 2',
            'CalculatedTable 2'[Year] = YEAR ( StartLastMonth )
                && 'CalculatedTable 2'[monthname] = MONTH ( StartLastMonth )
        )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( CountsLastMonth ),
        BLANK (),
        'CalculatedTable 2'[Counts] - CountsLastMonth
    )
        / CountsLastMonth

Comment: DAX comparison operations  do not support compare values of text with value of integer,consider using value of format to convert one of the values

Comment: Try converting the monthnames into month numbers in your source or by using the Power Query Editor

Comment: I converted the monthname into numbers and i got the  long decimal

Comment: Try choosing [%] on the Modeling tab under formatting

Comment: 2018 10 JAN SPN619 1 -0.999709234705746
2018 7 FEB SPN619 2 -0.999850990910445
2018 5 MAR SPN619 3 -0.999879459980714
2018 6 APR SPN619 4 -0.999849215922799
2018 32 MAY SPN619 5 -0.999174853665455

Comment: i changed data format to percentage and i got the below number 
-99.97 %
-99.99 %
-99.99 %
-99.98 %
-99.92 %
-99.97 %
-99.98 %
-99.98 %
-99.93 %
-99.99 %

Comment: FYI ,I am doing this calculation in   SSAS Tabular model

Comment: There is no modeling tab available ,i simply changed the column data type for that my calculated column

Comment: I have no more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

How about using below code:

```
SUM(Sheet1[records]) /CALCULATE(SUM('Sheet1'[records]), ALL('Sheet1'[Month]))
```